# Linear Model Aggregation

Tags: regression, model, linear, aggregation

I estimated 200'000 linear models from 200'000 individual data-sets with exactly the same data structure and simple model of the form Y ~ X. I would now like to report summary statistics on the estimates in an aggregate way across all 200'000 model estimates. Is there a convention on how to report such aggregate results? What fit measures are typically reported?

Comment: Are these non-overlapping data sets?

Comment: The data sets contain identical variables, but the values are data-set specific.

Comment: You may plot a histogram of the summary statistics if you want, but what it gives you? If I understand well: do you want to have a combined estimate of a pairwise regression Y ~ X having many sub-sample estimates? If so, you may use map-reduce algorithm for ordinary least squares to make a combined estimate.

Comment: No at this point I am only intersted in providing a summary of the individual estimates across those 200'000 estimations. A histogram makes sense, I was also thinking about reporting mean and median for the estimates as well as standard errors etc. To gather combined estimates we will consider map-reduce or a hierarchical model. Any additional thoughts on this approach would be appreciated?

Comment: If you are using Frequentist methods, you have 200,000 data sets and the model is the same then there is a theoretically correct disclosure.  Pearson-Neyman methods are about repeatability.  It is the repetition that matters.  You have done that in spades.  There are two mandatory disclosures, the rest is window dressing for completeness.  You need to report the number of times the null was falsified for your given threshold, such as 5% or 1%.  If you have not falsified the null $1-\alpha$ times, then you treat the null as true and you are done.  Otherwise report the mean slope(s).

Comment: It is the sampling distribution of your slopes and intercept that is of interest, so you should report the standard deviation of the slopes and intercepts.  A histogram isn't necessary at that volume unless you believe it is informative in some manner.  You should not report median statistics as they are not appropriate for the problem.  If you believe the median is more valuable than the mean, then with 200,000 repetitions, this implies your model is seriously wrong even if significant.

Comment: Finally, if your concern is not truth and hence not a null hypothesis question, but a location of the parameter question, then you could combine the sets using Bayesian updating and you would report the posterior density instead.  Because of the size of the data set, though, it would end up with the mean slope, as above.

Comment: Thank you David for your comprehensive and knowledeable answer to my problem,